# Mapping and generating an array from dynamic object

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic object like this

```
[  
   {  
      "displayFieldName":"",
      "fieldAliases":{  
         "OBJECTID":"OBJECTID"
      },
      "geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint",
      "spatialReference":{  
         "wkid":102100,
         "latestWkid":3857
      },
      "fields":[  
         {  
            "name":"OBJECTID",
            "type":"esriFieldTypeOID",
            "alias":"OBJECTID"
         }
      ],
      "features":[  
         {  
            "attributes":{  
               "OBJECTID":5270
            },
            "geometry":{  
               "x":-9814184.757,
               "y":5130582.574600004
            }
         },
         {  
            "attributes":{  
               "OBJECTID":5271
            },
            "geometry":{  
               "x":-9814152.5879,
               "y":
            }
         },
         {  
            "attributes":{  
               "OBJECTID":5272
            },
            "geometry":{  
               "x":-9814147.7353,
               "y":5130632.882600002
            }
         },
         ...
         ]
     }
]
```

How can I grab x and Y from the geometry nodes and load them to new array to be like

```
var points =  ['-9814184.757,5130582.574600004',
               '-9814152.5879, 5130624.636799999', 
                '-9814147.7353,5130632.882600002',
              ...,
              ]
```

I already tried this

```
map = data.map(a => a.geometry.x, a => a.geometry.x);
console.log(map);`
```

but it is just adding the x values into array.

Comment: Wouldn't you want each set in sub arrays? Like `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]`??

Comment: Actually I think it is even better option

Comment: Use [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I already tied this `map = data.map(a => a.geometry.x, a => a.geometry.x);
console.log(map);` but it is just adding the x values into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have correctly pointed in your question, you can use `Array.prototype.map` for this task. All you have to do is use `map` for the `features` array of your object as shown below:

```
/* Use 'map' to concatenate together each geometry value-pair into a string. */
var points = features.map((obj)=>obj.geometry.x + ", " + obj.geometry.y);
```

As an alternative, you can put each pair in sub-array with a little tweak to the code above:

```
/* Use 'map' to put each geometry value-pair into an array. */
var points = features.map((obj)=>[obj.geometry.x, obj.geometry.y]);
```

Check out the snippet below to see the full code in action.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* The 'features' array of your object. */
var features = [  
   {  
      "attributes":{  
         "OBJECTID":5270
      },
      "geometry":{  
         "x":-9814184.757,
         "y":5130582.574600004
      }
   },
   {  
      "attributes":{  
         "OBJECTID":5271
      },
      "geometry":{  
         "x":-9814152.5879,
         "y": 5130624.636799999
      }
   },
   {  
      "attributes":{  
         "OBJECTID":5272
      },
      "geometry":{  
         "x":-9814147.7353,
         "y":5130632.882600002
      }
   }
]

/* Use 'map' to concatenate together each geometry value-pair into a string. */
var points1 = features.map((obj)=>obj.geometry.x + ", " + obj.geometry.y);

/* Use 'map' to put each geometry value-pair into an array. */
var points2 = features.map((obj)=>[obj.geometry.x, obj.geometry.y]);

/* Log the results. */
console.log("as strings: ", points1);
console.log("as sub-arrays: ", points2);
```

Comment: Thanks Angel is there any way to have them as array of array like `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]`

Comment: Yes, sure @MonaCoder! I edited my answer to show you!

Comment: Thanks a lost this what I was looking for